# ¿ puedo usar un keypress de AngularJs dentro de un div y no un input?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directivas, div, teclado

Buenas,

Estoy empezando a hacer un juego que es un tablero de 100x100 en la pantalla, quiero poder reconocer cuando pulsan las fechas del teclado para que el jugador se mueva a lo largo del tablero, estoy usando AngularJS, para eso existe la directiva ng-keypress, pero parece que solo funciona dentro de un input, ¿alguien tiene otra idea?

Mi idea principal fue:

```
<div ng-keypress = press($event)> </div>
```

Otra idea seria en el body , pero no estoy seguro, seria algo así:

```
<body ng-keypress = press($event)> </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si es posible conocer que tecla pulsaron sin necesidad de estar en un `input` Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de como hacerlo:

```js
window.focus();
window.onkeydown = keypress

function keypress(){
 if (event.keyCode>=37 && event.keyCode<=40)
  console.log("pulso la tecla " + event.key)
}
```

```html
presiona las flechas de direccionamiento
```

La linea **`window.onkeydown`** corresponde al método del objecto window para disparar un evento al momento de presionar una tecla, dicho evento en principio no ejecuta ninguna acción pero si lo asociamos a la **función** **`= keypress`**, ejecutara dicha función y es por ello que cuando pulsas una tecla se ejecuta la **función** **`keypress`** que despliega en consola un mensaje que corresponde a una de las flechas de direccionamiento.

Comment: Ey muchas gracias, pero podrías colocarme el ejemplo de como lo llamas en el HTML, estoy un poco confundido, gracias de ante mano.

Comment: La linea **`window.onkeydown`** corresponde al método del objecto window para disparar un evento al momento de presionar una tecla, dicho evento en principio no ejecuta ninguna acción pero si lo asociamos a la **función** `= keypress`, ejecutara dicha función y es por ello que cuando pulsas una tecla se ejecuta la **función** **`keypress`** que despliega en consola un mensaje que corresponde a una de las flechas de direccionamiento.

Comment: Perfecto, ya entendí, muchísimas gracias!! en cuanto termine el juego se los comparto para que me den su opinión, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la respuesta a tu pregunta en Stack overflow en inglés, te dejo el enlace: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23651954/how-to-detect-pressed-keys-on-the-click-of-angularjs

Si batallas para el inglés, básicamente dice que hay varios métodos que puedes utilizar como `ng-keypress` o `ng-keyup` etc, y que no importa en que etiqueta html los pongas siempre y cuando respetes ciertas restricciones para Internet Explorer.

Checa esta documentación: [ngKeypress](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeypress)

Comment: Vale si, lo he leído pero cuando hago un ejemplo, colocando una llamada a ng-keypress dentro de otra etiqueta que no sea input, no hace nada, no me la detecta, como es para un juego, yo quiero que me lo detecte cuando hay una acción del teclado, o sea mayormente cuando pulse las teclas, dependiendo de eso yo hago algo, que principalmente es mover un cuadrado dentro de un cuadrado, de ante mano muchas gracias por tu respuesta.